# sql count function

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have three tables and I want to know how much jobs with the wage of 1000 an employee has had

The first SQL query gives me the names of all the employees that has recieved 1000 for a job

```
SELECT distinct first_name 
FROM employee, job, link 
WHERE job.wage = 1000 
  AND job.job_id = link.job_id and employee.employee_id = link.employee_id;
```

The second SQL query gives me the total number for all employees of how much jobs they have made for 1000

```
SELECT count(wage) 
FROM employee, job, link 
WHERE job.wage = 1000 
  AND job.job_id = link.job_id and employee.employee_id = link.employee_id;
```

I was wondering if there was a way of joining both queries and also making the second for each specific employee???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to use group by keyword

```
SELECT count(wage), first_name
FROM employee, job, link 
WHERE job.wage = 1000 
  AND job.job_id = link.job_id and employee.employee_id = link.employee_id;
GROUP BY first_name
```

the drawback on this would be if there are different employee has the same first_name it would consider to the same count.

Answer (score 1):

Something like below should work and you shouldn't need to the distinct first_name anymore.

```
select first_name, COUNT(wage) FROM employee, job, link  WHERE job.wage = 1000    AND job.job_id = link.job_id and employee.employee_id = link.employee_id
GROUP BY first_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend changing your implicit joins to explicit joins:

```
SELECT employee.employee_id, first_name, last_name, count(wage) as wage_count
FROM 
    employee
    JOIN link ON employee.employee_id = link.employee_id
    JOIN job ON job.job_id = link.job_id
WHERE job.wage = 1000 
GROUP BY employee.employee_id, first_name, last_name
```